# React-countdown-now not updating on render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I am creating a Mission Clock web app using React and Flux.

The code can be found here: https://github.com/jcadam14/Flux-Mission-Clock

Right now it's extremely basic, I'm new to React and Flux and it has been an extremely long time since I did any JavaScript (been in the monolithic Java application business for too long).  This is to get a proof of concept so I can base my design around React/Flux.

The basic concept is a "Next Contact" timer counts down and when it hits 1min before completion, the box the counter is in turns red.  Then when the NextContact timer completes, a CurrentContact timer starts, and a new NextContact timer should start.

Everything works fine up until the point where the NextContact component completes and is supposed to update with a new NextContact.  The text in the component and the style update, but the Countdown does not start ticking down.  It stays at the new value but doesn't start the timer.

Each time a render occurs because of some other reason, the NextContact component updates again with a new time but does not start counting.

However, if I save any change within any of the files (I'm using Visual Studio Code with module.hot active) then the counter starts and in fact picks up where it should be.  So it seems like something isn't getting fully rendered on change like I would expect.

I've tried using forceUpdate but that didn't do anything, and I've tried various ways of getting the Counter component but nothing works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm hoping once I get this down and can understand how all the dispatching stuff works the rest of the application should fall into place (the timers are a central component to the app, everything else is rather simple).

EDIT: I also tried writing just a simple timer app with Countdown but this time using Redux, and the same thing happens.  So I guess the question might be how do you force a component to re-initialize itself?

Thanks!
Jason

Answer (score 0):

Well I ended up just writing my own counter, here it is:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

const formatValues = ({days,hours,minutes,seconds}) =>
{
    const hourString = ('0' + hours).slice(-2);
    const minString = ('0'+ minutes).slice(-2);
    const secString = ('0' + seconds).slice(-2);
    return (days + ':' + hourString + ':' + minString + ':' + secString);
}

class MCCountdown extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            endDate:this.props.endDate,
            countdown:'0:00:00:00',
            secondRemaining:0,
            id:0
        }
        this.initializeCountdown = this.initializeCountdown.bind(this);
        this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)
    {
        if(this.props.endDate !== prevProps.endDate)
        {
            clearInterval(prevState.id);
            this.setState({endDate:this.props.endDate});
            this.initializeCountdown();
        }
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        this.initializeCountdown();
    }

    tick() {
        const values = this.getTimeRemaining(this.state.endDate);
        this.setState({countdown:formatValues(values),secondRemaining:values.secondsLeft});
        if(values.secondsLeft <= 0)
        {
            clearInterval(this.state.id);
            if(this.props.onComplete)
            {
                this.props.onComplete();
            }
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if(this.props.onTick)
            {
                this.props.onTick(this.state.secondRemaining);
            }
        }
      }

      getTimeRemaining(endtime){
        const total = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
        const seconds = Math.floor( (total/1000) % 60 );
        const minutes = Math.floor( (total/1000/60) % 60 );
        const hours = Math.floor( (total/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
        const days = Math.floor( total/(1000*60*60*24) );
        return {
          secondsLeft: total,
          days,
          hours,
          minutes,
          seconds
        };
    }

    initializeCountdown(){
        const values = this.getTimeRemaining(this.state.endDate);
        const id = setInterval(() => this.tick(),1000);
        this.setState({id:id,countdown:formatValues(values),secondRemaining:values.secondsLeft});
      }

    render()
    {
        const {countdown} = this.state;
        return(<div>{countdown}</div>);
    }
}

export default MCCountdown
```

This did the trick.  Seems like perhaps the timers/counters I have all tried might be missing that componentDidUpdate() method because once I added that to my MCCountdown, the clock restarts when a new date is set on the component.

Not sure if this is the pretties it can be but it works and I'm pretty darn happy with that right now.

Comment: Cancel the asynchronous task in the componentWillUnmount method.

`componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.state.id);
  }`